# Trying to get property of non-object yii2 php?

Tags: php, yii2

I have this error: Trying to get property of non-object

If i change the database to the same but different name, it works, but only once.

It has a problem with the returning data with the old database:  {return $data->modell->nev;},

```
[       
                'attribute' => 'modell',
                'value' => function($data)
                {return $data->modell->nev;},   
                'label' => 'Modell',    
],
```

What sould I change or write over?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

use the @ symbol to resolve the same issue

```
[       
                'attribute' => 'modell',
                'value' => function($data)
                {return @$data->modell->nev;},   
                'label' => 'Modell',    
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your relation

```
return ($relModel = $data->modell) ? $relModel->nev : ‘’;
```